# Fatal Error Layout.php on Frontend after staging environment setup

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, fatal-error, frontend-model

I have recently created a staging environment. Back-end works fine. But when I load my staging site I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Sidebar' not found in
>   /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 491

I have tried to fix it by clearing all kinds of Caches, and updating layout.php file (app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php):

```
$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->$callback[1]();
```

replaced with this one.

```
$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->{$callback[1]}();
```

It didn't work.

Can you please help me resolve this, please?

Comment: make sure the file `app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Block/Customer/Sidebar.php` exists and it is readable.

Comment: @Marius Wow this really helped, finally my staging site is up and running, however, it has different theme colors. I believe I can fix those from the theme configuration settings.

Answer (score 1):

There is only two scenario when you have this issue

1st as Marius said check the class file exist  :  `app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Block/Customer/Sidebar.php`

2Nd : please check `Mage_Whistlist` module is enable in `system->configuration->Advanced`